# Why is my TextView positioned differently in every list item?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have this layout for each item in my list:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/lock_closed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offerText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
            android:text="ad text here!" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/lockImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/lock_closed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/offerImage"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lockImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <com.example.customViews.AngledTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/offerImage"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:text="Large Text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0db7ff"
            android:text="@string/save" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/likeBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0db7ff"
            android:text="@string/like" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/unlikeBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0db7ff"
            android:text="@string/unlike" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

when I look at my list I see the text view in different places. How come?

[image]

[image]

Additionally I have implemented silent paging for my list.

Sometimes the list recycle takes too long and the user sees the photo replacement

(meaning the old item photo is replaced with the new item photo).

how can I make it more seamlessly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it aligned to the top of the lock image.  If the lock image isn't on your view, its not going to be properly anchored and will appear in slightly odd places.  Notice the failure case has no lock image.  The solution is to anchor it to something else in the y direction, so it isn't left floating without a lock image.  Another possibility is to set the lock image to INVISIBLE rather than GONE when its not shown, so it still has room reserved for it and the text view is aligned with where it would be if it existed.

Comment: thanks. how about my second q: Sometimes the list recycle takes too long and the user sees the photo replacement

(meaning the old item photo is replaced with the new item photo).

how can I make it more seamlessly ?